# parse “application/x-www-form-urlencoded” response with javascript

Tags: javascript

How do you parse a x-www-form-urlencoded string with JavaScript?
I tried to parse to JSON and able to iterate the keys using `Object.Keys()`

```
my responseText = {
    "response": {
        "header": {
            "error_code": 0
        },
        "body": {
            "foo": "foobar",
            "date": "2018-04-27"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not an "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" response. Please clarify. How are you getting the response text you provided to us?

Answer (score 0):

Url encoded forms have the structure `key=value&key2=value2&.......`

The keys and values are encoded, for more info on url encoding: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4

In case any value is an object with more keys and values inside it, the form will contain each of the keys inside said object as a description of their path relative to the root, using [].

Your example would look like:

```
response[header][error_code]=0&response[body][foo]=foobar&response[body][date]=2018-04-27
```

I think with this info you can probably figure it out, just keep in mind that the text is encoded, unlike in my example.